# parameterised query with IN - Odbc

Tags: c#, odbc

I haven't found a definitive answer on next question:
What is the most convenient way to use **"in"** operator in following case:
Example:

```
string testQuery = "SELECT * FROM ResultTable WHERE SUB_CODE in ?"; 

        try
        {
            using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(SQLConnectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (  OdbcCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())  
                {
                    cmd.CommandText = testQuery;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", OdbcType.NVarChar).Value = "(\'SB1\',\'SB2\',\'SBn-1\',\'SBn\')";   

                    using (OdbcDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {  
                           Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", reader[0]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }// catch etc.
```

Is there any other good way to do this without **"in"** operator?

Comment: What does "convenient" mean?

Comment: I mean - the right and appropriate way to run this query using IN(). I got OdbcException: ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0] [SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near '@P1'.